# pairwise.wilcox.test gives (I think) wrong results

Tags: r, statistics, comparison, difference

I would like to do a simple pairwise wilcox test with an easy (but crappy) data set. I have 8 groups and 5 values for each group (See data below). The groups are in the column "id" and the variable of interest, in this case weight, is in "weight". What I tried is:

```
pairwise.wilcox.test(dat$weight,dat$id, p.adj = "bonf")
```

which gives me the following result:

```
        286x306 286x339 286x574 547x286 574x519 574x542 574x547 587x210 589x286
286x339 0.36    -       -       -       -       -       -       -       -      
286x574 1.00    1.00    -       -       -       -       -       -       -      
547x286 0.36    1.00    0.36    -       -       -       -       -       -      
574x519 0.36    0.36    0.36    0.72    -       -       -       -       -      
574x542 0.36    0.36    0.36    0.36    0.36    -       -       -       -      
574x547 0.36    0.36    0.36    1.00    0.36    0.36    -       -       -      
587x210 1.00    1.00    1.00    0.36    0.36    1.00    0.36    -       -      
589x286 1.00    0.36    1.00    0.36    0.36    0.36    0.36    1.00    -      
WC      0.36    0.36    0.36    1.00    0.36    0.36    1.00    0.36    0.36
```

I do not understand that - I believe what I should get are p-values? I do not believe that there are no differences between the groups as the graph clearly shows them.
Does anyone have an idea what am I doing wrong? I would greatly appreciate every help!

```
    id  weight  V3
1   286x306 110 1
2   286x306 126 1
3   286x306 121 1
4   286x306 115 1
5   286x306 105 1
6   286x339 194 2
7   286x339 181 2
8   286x339 200 2
9   286x339 140 2
10  286x339 142 2
11  286x574 143 3
12  286x574 136 3
13  286x574 118 3
14  286x574 151 3
15  286x574 124 3
16  547x286 280 4
17  547x286 225 4
18  547x286 192 4
19  547x286 273 4
20  547x286 221 4
21  574x519 331 5
22  574x519 332 5
23  574x519 301 5
24  574x519 320 5
25  574x519 280 5
26  574x542 81  6
27  574x542 89  6
28  574x542 103 6
29  574x542 94  6
30  574x542 93  6
31  574x547 222 7
32  574x547 203 7
33  574x547 243 7
34  574x547 223 7
35  574x547 227 7
36  587x210 140 8
37  587x210 145 8
38  587x210 103 8
39  587x210 137 8
40  587x210 95  8
41  589x286 125 9
42  589x286 120 9
43  589x286 108 9
44  589x286 126 9
45  589x286 119 9
46  WC  227 10
47  WC  228 10
48  WC  232 10
49  WC  221 10
50  WC  229 10
```

Comment: please reproduce the example with synthetic data or share your data.

Comment: I have added the complete data set - thanks for coming back to me! If I don't do the bonferoni correction I get the same results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is due to the Bonferoni correction, which adjusts p-values for the number of tests you conduct. Example:

```
airquality$Month <- factor(airquality$Month, labels = month.abb[5:9])

#test without correction for multiple testing
res0 <- pairwise.wilcox.test(airquality$Ozone,airquality$Month, p.adj = "none")
#    May     Jun     Jul     Aug    
#Jun 0.19250 -       -       -      
#Jul 3e-05   0.01414 -       -      
#Aug 0.00012 0.02591 0.86195 -      
#Sep 0.11859 0.95887 0.00074 0.00325
#
#P value adjustment method: none 

#manual correction
m <- length(na.omit(c(res0$p.value)))
matrix(pmin(1, res0$p.value*m), ncol=ncol(res0$p.value))
#            [,1]      [,2]        [,3]       [,4]
#[1,] 1.000000000        NA          NA         NA
#[2,] 0.000299639 0.1413625          NA         NA
#[3,] 0.001208078 0.2590776 1.000000000         NA
#[4,] 1.000000000 1.0000000 0.007442604 0.03247955

#this gives the same
pairwise.wilcox.test(airquality$Ozone, airquality$Month, p.adj = "bonf")
#    May    Jun    Jul    Aug   
#Jun 1.0000 -      -      -     
#Jul 0.0003 0.1414 -      -     
#Aug 0.0012 0.2591 1.0000 -     
#Sep 1.0000 1.0000 0.0074 0.0325
#
#P value adjustment method: bonferroni
```

You might want to use a less conservative correction (see `help("p.adjust")` for alternatives). Maybe you could adjust the false discovery rate?